# Why isn't any basic html content showing up in my body?

Tags: html, css, header

I've begun making a basic porfolio page and I'm starting with a simple header that I want at the top center of the white space of the page, and it seems to be hidden or just not there at all. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong? Link to site: http://me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/portfolio/portfolio.html

Here is the HTML bit i'm focusing on:

```
    <div class="header"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>
```

and the entire CSS for the whole site is:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;

}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline; 

}

a { 
    color: grey; 
    text-decoration: inherit;
} 


a:hover{
    color: black;

}

.current {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    display: table; 
}

.wrapper {
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right:0 auto;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    text-align:center;

}

h1 {
    font-family:"Kaushan Script";
    font-size: 4em; 
    color:#FADBC8 ;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Poiret One";

}

#header {
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;

}

.photo img {
    width: 12%;
    height: 12%;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: 3px solid #FADBC8;
    margin-top:30px;

}

#sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: "Poiret One";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    background: #F9DBC8;

}

#sidebar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0;

}

/* drop down menu */

#sidebar ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 70%;
}


#sidebar ul li ul {
    margin: 0;  
}

#sidebar ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.social-sidebar-buttons {
    float: right;
    width: 3%;
    margin-top: 31%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder: it's helpful to mark an accepted answer using the checkmark next to the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your css you have 'header' as id and not a class, use the dot notation for a class

```
.header {
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;

}
```

adding `margin:auto;` will center the div in the middle. It automatically gives even spacing either side.

Comment: No problem, I'm always doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. your defining a class but styling a id selector.

1.) remove the below.

```
#header { ... }
```

2.) replace with.

```
.header { ... }
```

3.) You need to define a height, you can keep your existing style you had associated with misplaced `#header` but a few additional suggestions below:

```
.header { 
     height: 100px; // define height
     margin: 0 auto; // center if you want
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

You have multiple closed head tags and you haven't defined a class for your header.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.header {
    text-align:center;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;

}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Chloe Hammond - Digital Portfolio</title>
<link href="stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script|Kaushan+Script|Poiret+One'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!--METADATA-->
<meta name="description" content="A digital portfolio page showcasing Chloe Hammond's most recent projects from her New Media degree course at the University of Leeds. "/>

<meta name="keywords" content="chloe, hammond, portfolio, digital, new, media, experience, contact, work, university, student, leeds, intern, internship, freelance"/>
</head>



<body>
<div id="sidebar"> 
    <h2><ul>
        <li><a href="index2.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo.html">Photo</li>
            <li><a href="motion.html">Motion</li>
            <li><a href="web.html">Web</li>
         </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="about2.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact2.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul></h2>
    </div>

   <div class="header"><h1>Portfolio</h1></div>

    <div class="social-sidebar-buttons">   

     <a href="http://www.facebook.com/chloe.hammond.7"><img src="facebook2.png" target="_blank" alt="Connect with Chloe on Facebook"/></a>                                              
  <a href="https://twitter.com/ChloeHammondx" title="twitter"><img src="twitter2.png" target="_blank" alt="Connect with Chloe on Twitter" /></a>

<a href="https://instagram.com/chloelouisehammond/" title="Instagram"><img src="instagram2.png" target="_blank" alt="View Chloe's Instagram feed" /></a>

<a href="mailto:chloehammond@live.co.uk" title="email"><img src="mailto2.png" target="_blank" alt="Email Chloe" /></a> 
    </div> 

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.